# Simple C++ regular expressions library for VS 2008 w/o Feature Pack

Tags: c++, regex, windows, winapi, mfc

I am working on a MFC/C++ project that is being developed in VS 2008 without the Feature Pack. (The reason that I'm not using the feature pack is because this project needs to be backwards compatible with Win2K, which the pack obsoletes.)

So I'm looking to do some simple regular expression matching.

I did some search and most of what I was able to find was either not available for inclusion into a commercial project (which mine is) or the library itself is too heavy for my need (Boost.Regex for instance.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I'd use Boost 1.54 but not thier libraries, just thier source code.
Install the full boost distribution. In your project, add C++ files by selecting all
the files in `..\boost_1_54_0\libs\regex\src\*.*` and of course add the header path's.

Big advantage in that the regex src is just code, and conforms well to your project settings and therefore your project is not dependent on thier libraries.

This is a very small footprint in your codesize. However, you can also just duplicate most  of your project settings to make a seperate lib/dll of the regex source, then include that in your other project.

With boost, there is no licensing problems with commercial code as long as its not distributed with it (even then, you just give attribution).

I gotta tell ya, boost regex is a fabulous engine.

---

**Edit2:** 
The answer to your `What libs do I need to include?` is NONE if you add the regex source to your project. There are no libs because all the code becomes part of your executable.

All you have to do is tell your project  the directory where the distribution is installed (see below). The source files you added will include the HPP files it needs. Just compile.

From my code, it looks like the footprint is 2-300K, which isin't that bad.
boost regex is almost all template class hpp files, it fits nicely with C++.
You can see from my samples, I use iterators quite extensively, its the way to go.

I use quite a lot of regexs. I keep them in a `myconst.h/cpp` model, and include where needed. I also use a program called RegexFormat ([website](http://regexformat.com)) to manage them. Formats/compress/expand/debugs and converts back and forth from/to C++ strings. Makes it easy.. Just checked, they lowered the price to 29 bucks. (I got it at 49, oh well).

There are many more ways to use boost regex.
Here is a small usage sample. I tried to cut it down without sacraficing meaning.
It still looks big (Sorry SO).

Don't hesitate to ask if you have any more questions...

```
 Project Properties
 -------------------
 Configuration Properties ->
       C/C++ ->
           General ->
             Additional Include Directories ->
                F:\Dev\boost_1_54_0    ( <-where you install the distribution )



 //////////////////////////////////////////////
 // ======== myconst.h ==========
 #pragma once

 #ifndef _myconst
 #define _myconst

 //
 #include <boost/regex.hpp>
 #include <string> 
 #include <iostream> 

 // ------------------------

 using namespace std;
 using namespace stdext;
 using namespace boost;

 // ---------------------------------------------
 typedef std::string::const_iterator SITR;

 #define MOD    regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s | boost::regex::no_mod_m 
 #define MODx   regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s | boost::regex::no_mod_m | regex_constants::mod_x
 #define MODs   regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_m | regex_constants::mod_s
 #define MODxs  regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_m | regex_constants::mod_s | regex_constants::mod_x

 #define MODm   regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s  
 #define MODxm  regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s| regex_constants::mod_x
 #define MODsm  regex_constants::perl | regex_constants::mod_s
 #define MODxsm regex_constants::perl | regex_constants::mod_s | regex_constants::mod_x

 // Common regexes

 extern boost::regex  TextLine;
 extern boost::regex  TRI_TextLineReplace;
 extern boost::regex  TextLineReplace;
 extern boost::regex  BlankLinesReplace; 
 extern boost::regex  StripBoundryWsp;

 #endif _myconst  // End _myconst
 //
 //////////////////////////////////////////////


 //////////////////////////////////////////////
 // ======== myconst.cpp ==========
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "myconst.h"

  boost::regex  TextLine (
    " (?| ( [^\\r\\n]* ) \\r\\n | ( [^\\r\\n]+ ) \\z )   "
     , MODx);
  boost::regex  TRI_TextLineReplace (                 // with support to escape trigraph '??x' sequence
    " ( [\\\\\"] | \\?(?=\\?) | (?<=\\?)\\? )  "
     , MODx);
  boost::regex  TextLineReplace (                     // no support to escape trigraph '??x' sequence
    " ( [\\\\\"] )  "
     , MODx);
  boost::regex StripBoundryWsp ("\\A \\s*(?=\\S) (.+?) (?<=\\S)\\s* \\z", MODxs);

  boost::regex  BlankLinesReplace (
    " (?:     "
    "       (?> \\A  [^\\S\\r\\n]* (?: \\z | (?=\\r\\n) ) )         "
    "    |  (?> (?<=\\r\\n) [^\\S\\r\\n]* (?: \\z | (?=\\r\\n) ) )  "
    "  )                                                            "
     , MODx);
 //
 //////////////////////////////////////////////


 //////////////////////////////////////////////
 // ======== myeditor.cpp ==========
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "myconst.h"
 #include "myeditor.h"
 #include "makecstrdlg.h"


 LRESULT MyEditor::OnMsgMakeCstring(WPARAM /*wp*/, LPARAM /*lp*/)
 {
     CMakeCstrDlg dlg;
     if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
     {
         if ( dlg.m_bType2 )
         {
             CString mfcstr;
             GetWindowText( mfcstr );
             string strSrc = mfcstr;

             GetMakeCstrType2( strSrc, dlg.bTrigraph );          

             SetWindowText( strSrc.c_str() );
         }
     }
     SetFocus(); 
     return 0;
 }

 void MyEditor::GetMakeCstrType2( string& strSrc, bool bTrigraph )
 {
    if ( strSrc.length() == 0 )
    {
        strSrc.assign("\"\"");  // '""'
        return;
    }


    boost::regex Replacer;

    if ( bTrigraph )
        Replacer = TRI_TextLineReplace;
    else
        Replacer = TextLineReplace;

    string strNewSrc = "";
    string tmp;

    SITR _Mstart;
    SITR _Mend;
    boost::smatch _M;

    _Mstart = strSrc.begin();
    _Mend   = strSrc.end();

    while ( boost::regex_search ( _Mstart, _Mend, _M, TextLine ) )
    {
        tmp.assign( _M[1].first, _M[1].second );
        tmp  = boost::regex_replace ( tmp, Replacer, "\\\\$1" );

        strNewSrc.append( "\"" + tmp );
        strNewSrc.append( "\\n\"\r\n" );

        _Mstart = _M[0].second;
    }
    strSrc = strNewSrc;
 }
 //
 //////////////////////////////////////////////
```

---

Edit:  If you use boost regex, below will help you

Preprocessor: These boost defines will work well

```
   Boost Defines (in Project Settings)
   =================================
   BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
   BOOST_REGEX_NON_RECURSIVE
   BOOST_REGEX_BLOCKSIZE=32768
   BOOST_REGEX_MAX_BLOCKS=8192
   BOOST_REGEX_MAX_CACHE_BLOCKS=4096
```

This fixes an annoying warning due to MS can't control thier own header files

```
   =================================================

   #include <intsafe.h>
   #include <stdint.h>

   CAUSES THIS ->


   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(72): warning C4005: 'INT8_MIN' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(144) : see previous definition of 'INT8_MIN'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(73): warning C4005: 'INT16_MIN' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(146) : see previous definition of 'INT16_MIN'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(74): warning C4005: 'INT32_MIN' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(148) : see previous definition of 'INT32_MIN'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(76): warning C4005: 'INT8_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(167) : see previous definition of 'INT8_MAX'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(77): warning C4005: 'INT16_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(171) : see previous definition of 'INT16_MAX'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(78): warning C4005: 'INT32_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(176) : see previous definition of 'INT32_MAX'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(79): warning C4005: 'UINT8_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(168) : see previous definition of 'UINT8_MAX'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(80): warning C4005: 'UINT16_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(173) : see previous definition of 'UINT16_MAX'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(81): warning C4005: 'UINT32_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(178) : see previous definition of 'UINT32_MAX'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(149): warning C4005: 'INT64_MIN' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(152) : see previous definition of 'INT64_MIN'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(150): warning C4005: 'INT64_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(184) : see previous definition of 'INT64_MAX'
   1>f:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(151): warning C4005: 'UINT64_MAX' : macro redefinition
   1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\intsafe.h(189) : see previous definition of 'UINT64_MAX'




   Fix 1 (preferred):
   ====================================================

   In "\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h" undefine them before they  are re-defined


   #undef INT8_MIN
   #undef INT16_MIN
   #undef INT32_MIN
   #undef INT8_MAX
   #undef INT16_MAX
   #undef INT32_MAX
   #undef UINT8_MAX
   #undef UINT16_MAX
   #undef UINT32_MAX
   #undef INT64_MIN
   #undef INT64_MAX
   #undef UINT64_MAX


   Fix 2:
   ====================================================
   In "\boost\config\compiler\visualc.hpp"  undefine BOOST_HAS_STDINT_H


   //#if _MSC_VER >= 1600
   #undef BOOST_HAS_STDINT_H
   //#  define BOOST_HAS_STDINT_H
   //#endif
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a very good idea. I've never used Boost though. Can you give me just a simple example of how you'd use, say, a regexp on a string match? And also what libs do you include from that folder you named above?

Comment: @c00000fd - No libs. Posted an explanation with a typical sample above.

Comment: Thanks. That Boost is not just a bunch of cpp/h files. I did the first part of your code (`myconst` section) and got, `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_55.lib'` while building the project. Evidently I need to install it or build something in it...

Comment: @c00000fd - Not possible. `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_55.lib` is a multi-threaded lib. There are 7 or 8 libs that could be used. The only way the linker would try to open a specific lib is if its in your linker statement. Take it out. Are you including the regex `src` files in your project? All you need to do is add the include path to the distribution heirechy folder (the one where you installed the distribution). The sub-directory will have `boost` in it, set the path to the parent folder.

Comment: @c00000fd - I forgot, you have to tell it to `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` in your defines. Add the defines (I posted above) to your project settings. This prevents auto-sensing config from trying to load a library.

Comment: @c00000fd - Try this link [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html), read at the bottom **Building from Source** But, you still need `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` defined at the project level because config.hpp will auto-link a lib based on your project settings. When you get it to compile, read some of the regex documentation for many ways to use it. Including ICU support (Unicode chars  in regexes). I didn't install ICU because I use ascii in regexes.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on this, but unfortunately I wasn't able to make your method work. Have you tried it yourself? I ended up building the full Boost library, which took about 2.4GB on disc -- which is WAY an overkill for my purposes. So I will be looking for a better solution. In the meanwhile, this seems to be the only viable answer to my question. Others don't provide a reliable RegExp engine.

Comment: Hi @ahmd0 - Defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and including the install path and adding the src mentioned, it works everytime, can't work anyway else. I guess I tried it, I have a commercial product on sale that uses it. I think you are confusing the Boost _Regex_ with the entire Boost library.. it isin't. It appears you are now Auto-Linking with the library you build, where that was not necessary. Did you follow the link [**Building from Source**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

Boost is a good answer, but may be a smaller implementation is sufficient and may have less side effects if you never used Boost before.

[Atl Server](http://atlserver.codeplex.com/) (on Codeplex) has also a regular expression engine in [atlrx.h](http://atlserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#include/atlrx.h)
Documented also in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wzck77h4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You find sample code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13320/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-MFC) too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I couldn't locate a C++ implementation that was compatible with the modern RegExp standards and wasn't buggy... have to stick with the Boost.

Answer (score 0):

There's an old but widely used regex library written by [Henry Spencer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Spencer) and included in probably hundreds of products. Here's one of the many places where you can get it:

http://www.arglist.com/regex/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I couldn't locate a C++ implementation that was compatible with the modern RegExp standards and wasn't buggy...